# How to pan the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have these event listeners in my code

```
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown,false);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp, false);
```

These functions will help me to pan the canvas. I have declared a variable in the `onLoad` called `pan`, `isDown`, `mousePostion` and previous mouse positions.  Then in the initialise function is set the `pan`,`mousePos` and `premousepos` to vectors containing 0,0

```
function draw() {
    context.translate(pan.getX(), pan.getY());
    topPerson.draw(context);
    console.log(pan);
}

function onMouseDown(event) {
    var x = event.offsetX;
    var y = event.offsetY;
    var mousePosition = new vector(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);

    previousMousePosition = mousePosition;

    isDown = true;

    console.log(previousMousePosition);
    console.log("onmousedown" + "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y);
}

function onMouseUp(event) {
    isDown = false;
}


function onMouseMove(event) {
    if (isDown) {
        console.log(event.offsetX);
        mousePosition = new vector(event.offsetX, event.offsetY);
        newMousePosition = mousePosition;
        console.log('mouseMove' + newMousePosition);

        var panX = newMousePosition.getX() - previousMousePosition.getX();
        var panY = newMousePosition.getY() - previousMousePosition.getY();
        console.log('onMouseMove:  ' + panX);
        pan = new vector(panX, panY);
        console.log('mouseMove' + pan);

    }
}
```

But it is not registering the new `pan` Values so you could attempt to drag the canvas. I know my mouse dragging events work but is just doesnt `pan`.

Answer (score 20):

**Here's a simple (annotated) example of panning code**

It works by accumulating the net amount the mouse has been dragged horizontally (and vertically) Then it redraws everything, but offset by those accumulated horizontal & vertical distances.

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
// canvas related variables
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
// account for scrolling
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// mouse drag related variables
var isDown=false;
var startX,startY;

// the accumulated horizontal(X) & vertical(Y) panning the user has done in total
var netPanningX=0;
var netPanningY=0;

// just for demo: display the accumulated panning
var $results=$('#results');

// draw the numbered horizontal & vertical reference lines
for(var x=0;x<100;x++){ ctx.fillText(x,x*20,ch/2); }
for(var y=-50;y<50;y++){ ctx.fillText(y,cw/2,y*20); }

// listen for mouse events
$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // calc the starting mouse X,Y for the drag
  startX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  startY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // set the isDragging flag
  isDown=true;
}

function handleMouseUp(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // clear the isDragging flag
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseOut(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // clear the isDragging flag
  isDown=false;
}

function handleMouseMove(e){

  // only do this code if the mouse is being dragged
  if(!isDown){return;}
  
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  // get the current mouse position
  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // dx & dy are the distance the mouse has moved since
  // the last mousemove event
  var dx=mouseX-startX;
  var dy=mouseY-startY;

  // reset the vars for next mousemove
  startX=mouseX;
  startY=mouseY;

  // accumulate the net panning done
  netPanningX+=dx;
  netPanningY+=dy;
  $results.text('Net change in panning: x:'+netPanningX+'px, y:'+netPanningY+'px'); 

  // display the horizontal & vertical reference lines
  // The horizontal line is offset leftward or rightward by netPanningX
  // The vertical line is offset upward or downward by netPanningY
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  for(var x=-50;x<50;x++){ ctx.fillText(x,x*20+netPanningX,ch/2); }
  for(var y=-50;y<50;y++){ ctx.fillText(y,cw/2,y*20+netPanningY); }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id=results>Drag the mouse to see net panning in x,y directions</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
```

Comment: Hey @markE, I know that this question is quite old, but I was wondering if you could answer a quick question; how does the panning actually work? it may just be because i'm tired, but i can't see how those last two lines actually cause the content to pan

Comment: this one got me going, but after I pan the image and use getImageData(), the panned image-data under the canvas is missing. Any help on this one?

Answer (score 17):

**To answer question**

You have not provided some of the code. Specifically the vector object you are creating each event, could be there. (really you should not be creating a new object each time. Create once and update the values)

What I do see is that mouseMove events do not update the previous mouse position object so you will only get panning from the last mouse down. But you may want that. So without the code I don't know what is wrong as the code given is OK.

Below is how I do the whole shabang..

**How to pan (and zoom).**

Below is an example of panning and zooming with the mouse. Its a little more complex than standard pan and zooms, that is because I have added some smoothing to the pan and zoom to give it a better interactive feel.

**How it works.**

The canvas uses a transformation matrix to transform points. What this does is maintain that matrix. I call the transformed space, real space. I also maintain an inverse matrix, that is used to convert from screen space into real space.

The core of the demo is around the object `displayTransform` it holds the matrix, all the individual values needed, and the functions `update()` call once a frame, `setHome()` get the screen space transform and applies it to the canvas. Used to clear the screen. And `setTransform()` this set the canvas to real space (the zoomed panned space)

To smooth out movements I have a mirror of the values `x, y, ox, oy, scale,` and `rotate`. ((ox,oy) are origin x and y) (and yes rotate works) each of these variable has a delta prefixed with d and a chaser prefixed with c. The chaser values chase the required values. You should not touch the chaser values. There are two values called `drag` and `accel` (short for acceleration) `drag` (not real simulated drag) is how quickly the deltas decay. Values for `drag` > 0.5 will result in a bouncy response. As you get toward one it will get more and more bouncy. At 1 the bound will not stop, above one and it's unusable. 'accel' is how quickly the transform responds to mouse movement. Low values are slow response, 0 is no response at all, and one is instant response. Play with the values to find what you like.

Example of the logic for chaser values

```
var x = 100; // the value to be chased
var dx = 0; // the delta x or the change in x per frame
var cx = 0; // the chaser value. This value chases x;
var drag = 0.1;  // quick decay
var accel = 0.9; // quick follpw
// logic
dx += (x-cx)*accel; // get acceleration towards x
dx *= drag;          // apply the drag
cx += dx;           // change chaser by delta x.
```

**Convert coords**

No point having a zoom panned rotated canvas if you don't know where things are. To do this I keep an inverse matrix. It converts screen x and y into realspace x and y. For convenience I convert the mouse to real space every update. If you want the reverse realSpace to screen space. then its just

```
var x; // real x coord (position in the zoom panned rotate space)
var y; // real y coord

// "this" is displayTransform
x -= this.cx;
y -= this.cy;    
// screenX and screen Y are the screen coordinates.
screenX = (x * this.matrix[0] + y * this.matrix[2])+this.cox;
screenY = (x * this.matrix[1] + y * this.matrix[3])+this.coy;
```

You can see it at the end of the mouse `displayTransform.update` where I use the inverse transform to convert the mouse screen coords to real coords. Then in the main update loop I use the mouse real coords to display the help text. I leave it up to the user of the code to create a function that will convert any screen coord. (easy just pinch the bit where the mouse is being converted).

**Zoom**

The zoom is done with the mouse wheel. This presents a bit of a problem and naturally you expect the zoom to be centered on the mouse. But the transform is actually relative to the top left of the screen. To fix this I also keep an origin x and y. This basically floats about until the wheel zoom is needed then it is set to the mouse real position, and the mouse distance from the top left is placed in the transform x and y position. Then just increase or decrease the scale to zoom in and out. I have left the origin and offset to float (not set the chase values) this works for the current drag and acceleration setting but if you notice that it's not working that well with other setting set the the cx, cy, cox, coy values as well. ( I have added a note in the code)

**Pan**

Pan is done with the left mouse button. Click and drag to pan. This is straight forward. I get the difference between the last mouse position and the new one screen space (the coords given by the mouse events) This gives me a mouse delta vector. I transform the delta mouse vector into real space and subtract that from the top left coords `displayTransform.x` and `displayTransform.y`. Thats it I let the chaser x and y smooth it all out.

The snippet just displays a large image that can be panned and zoomed. I check for the complete flag rather than use onload. While the image is loading the snippet will just display loading. The main loop is refreshed with requestAnimationFrame, first I update the `displayTransform` then the canvas is cleared in home space (screen space) and then the image is displayed in real space. As always I a fighting time so will return as time permits to add more comments, and maybe a function or two.

If you find the chase variables a little to much, you can just remove them and replace all the c prefixed vars with the unprefixed ones.

OK hope this helps. Not done yet as need to clean up but need to do some real work for a bit.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canV"); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var mouse = {
    x : 0,
    y : 0,
    w : 0,
    alt : false,
    shift : false,
    ctrl : false,
    buttonLastRaw : 0, // user modified value
    buttonRaw : 0,
    over : false,
    buttons : [1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3], // masks for setting and clearing button raw bits;
};
function mouseMove(event) {
    mouse.x = event.offsetX;
    mouse.y = event.offsetY;
    if (mouse.x === undefined) {
        mouse.x = event.clientX;
        mouse.y = event.clientY;
    }
    mouse.alt = event.altKey;
    mouse.shift = event.shiftKey;
    mouse.ctrl = event.ctrlKey;
    if (event.type === "mousedown") {
        event.preventDefault()
        mouse.buttonRaw |= mouse.buttons[event.which-1];
    } else if (event.type === "mouseup") {
        mouse.buttonRaw &= mouse.buttons[event.which + 2];
    } else if (event.type === "mouseout") {
        mouse.buttonRaw = 0;
        mouse.over = false;
    } else if (event.type === "mouseover") {
        mouse.over = true;
    } else if (event.type === "mousewheel") {
        event.preventDefault()
        mouse.w = event.wheelDelta;
    } else if (event.type === "DOMMouseScroll") { // FF you pedantic doffus
       mouse.w = -event.detail;
    }
  

}

function setupMouse(e) {
    e.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('mouseout', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('mouseover', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('mousewheel', mouseMove);
    e.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', mouseMove); // fire fox
    
    e.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
}
setupMouse(canvas);


// terms.
// Real space, real, r (prefix) refers to the transformed canvas space.
// c (prefix), chase is the value that chases a requiered value
var displayTransform = {
    x:0,
    y:0,
    ox:0,
    oy:0,
    scale:1,
    rotate:0,
    cx:0,  // chase values Hold the actual display
    cy:0,
    cox:0,
    coy:0,
    cscale:1,
    crotate:0,
    dx:0,  // deltat values
    dy:0,
    dox:0,
    doy:0,
    dscale:1,
    drotate:0,
    drag:0.1,  // drag for movements
    accel:0.7, // acceleration
    matrix:[0,0,0,0,0,0], // main matrix
    invMatrix:[0,0,0,0,0,0], // invers matrix;
    mouseX:0,
    mouseY:0,
    ctx:ctx,
    setTransform:function(){
        var m = this.matrix;
        var i = 0;
        this.ctx.setTransform(m[i++],m[i++],m[i++],m[i++],m[i++],m[i++]);
    },
    setHome:function(){
        this.ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
        
    },
    update:function(){
        // smooth all movement out. drag and accel control how this moves
        // acceleration 
        this.dx += (this.x-this.cx)*this.accel;
        this.dy += (this.y-this.cy)*this.accel;
        this.dox += (this.ox-this.cox)*this.accel;
        this.doy += (this.oy-this.coy)*this.accel;
        this.dscale += (this.scale-this.cscale)*this.accel;
        this.drotate += (this.rotate-this.crotate)*this.accel;
        // drag
        this.dx *= this.drag;
        this.dy *= this.drag;
        this.dox *= this.drag;
        this.doy *= this.drag;
        this.dscale *= this.drag;
        this.drotate *= this.drag;
        // set the chase values. Chase chases the requiered values
        this.cx += this.dx;
        this.cy += this.dy;
        this.cox += this.dox;
        this.coy += this.doy;
        this.cscale += this.dscale;
        this.crotate += this.drotate;
        
        // create the display matrix
        this.matrix[0] = Math.cos(this.crotate)*this.cscale;
        this.matrix[1] = Math.sin(this.crotate)*this.cscale;
        this.matrix[2] =  - this.matrix[1];
        this.matrix[3] = this.matrix[0];

        // set the coords relative to the origin
        this.matrix[4] = -(this.cx * this.matrix[0] + this.cy * this.matrix[2])+this.cox;
        this.matrix[5] = -(this.cx * this.matrix[1] + this.cy * this.matrix[3])+this.coy;        


        // create invers matrix
        var det = (this.matrix[0] * this.matrix[3] - this.matrix[1] * this.matrix[2]);
        this.invMatrix[0] = this.matrix[3] / det;
        this.invMatrix[1] =  - this.matrix[1] / det;
        this.invMatrix[2] =  - this.matrix[2] / det;
        this.invMatrix[3] = this.matrix[0] / det;
        
        // check for mouse. Do controls and get real position of mouse.
        if(mouse !== undefined){  // if there is a mouse get the real cavas coordinates of the mouse
            if(mouse.oldX !== undefined && (mouse.buttonRaw & 1)===1){ // check if panning (middle button)
                var mdx = mouse.x-mouse.oldX; // get the mouse movement
                var mdy = mouse.y-mouse.oldY;
                // get the movement in real space
                var mrx = (mdx * this.invMatrix[0] + mdy * this.invMatrix[2]);
                var mry = (mdx * this.invMatrix[1] + mdy * this.invMatrix[3]);   
                this.x -= mrx;
                this.y -= mry;
            }
            // do the zoom with mouse wheel
            if(mouse.w !== undefined && mouse.w !== 0){
                this.ox = mouse.x;
                this.oy = mouse.y;
                this.x = this.mouseX;
                this.y = this.mouseY;
                /* Special note from answer */
                // comment out the following is you change drag and accel
                // and the zoom does not feel right (lagging and not 
                // zooming around the mouse 
                /*
                this.cox = mouse.x;
                this.coy = mouse.y;
                this.cx = this.mouseX;
                this.cy = this.mouseY;
                */
                if(mouse.w > 0){ // zoom in
                    this.scale *= 1.1;
                    mouse.w -= 20;
                    if(mouse.w < 0){
                        mouse.w = 0;
                    }
                }
                if(mouse.w < 0){ // zoom out
                    this.scale *= 1/1.1;
                    mouse.w += 20;
                    if(mouse.w > 0){
                        mouse.w = 0;
                    }
                }

            }
            // get the real mouse position 
            var screenX = (mouse.x - this.cox);
            var screenY = (mouse.y - this.coy);
            this.mouseX = this.cx + (screenX * this.invMatrix[0] + screenY * this.invMatrix[2]);
            this.mouseY = this.cy + (screenX * this.invMatrix[1] + screenY * this.invMatrix[3]);            
            mouse.rx = this.mouseX;  // add the coordinates to the mouse. r is for real
            mouse.ry = this.mouseY;
            // save old mouse position
            mouse.oldX = mouse.x;
            mouse.oldY = mouse.y;
        }
        
    }
}
// image to show
var img = new Image();
img.src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e5/Fiat_500_in_Emilia-Romagna.jpg"
// set up font
ctx.font = "14px verdana";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
// timer for stuff
var timer =0;
function update(){
    timer += 1; // update timere
    // update the transform
    displayTransform.update();
    // set home transform to clear the screem
    displayTransform.setHome();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    // if the image loaded show it
    if(img.complete){
        displayTransform.setTransform();
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
        if(Math.floor(timer/100)%2 === 0){
            ctx.fillText("Left but to pan",mouse.rx,mouse.ry);
        }else{
            ctx.fillText("Wheel to zoom",mouse.rx,mouse.ry);
        }
    }else{
        // waiting for image to load
        displayTransform.setTransform();
        ctx.fillText("Loading image...",100,100);
        
    }
    if(mouse.buttonRaw === 4){ // right click to return to homw
         displayTransform.x = 0;
         displayTransform.y = 0;
         displayTransform.scale = 1;
         displayTransform.rotate = 0;
         displayTransform.ox = 0;
         displayTransform.oy = 0;
     }
    // reaquest next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
update(); // start it happening
```

```css
.canC { width:400px;  height:400px;}
div {
  font-size:x-small;
}
```

```html
<div>Wait for image to load and use <b>left click</b> drag to pan, and <b>mouse wheel</b> to zoom in and out. <b>Right click</b> to return to home scale and pan. Image is 4000 by 2000 plus so give it time if you have a slow conection. Not the tha help text follows the mouse in real space. Image from wiki commons</div>
<canvas class="canC" id="canV" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```