# Webpage interaction/navigation in all directions OR viewport with off canvas content left, top, right and bottom that is scrollable

Tags: html, css, canvas, viewport, interaction

I am looking into different ways of navigating or interacting with a web page and I have had an idea that I cant work out a solution too.

Essentially on website load I would like the viewport to load in the middle of a much larger canvas that can then be navigated in all directions, up, right, down, left either with touch/swipe, arrow keys or swiping.

Has anybody achieved or seen an example of this so I can inspect the code?

[Diagram of desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4cij.png)

Comment: Are you talking about [Parallax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) webiste?

Comment: Not really – traditionally when you load a website you scroll either top to bottom or left to right. I would like to be able to scroll in all directions from page load so, scroll up, or scroll left, or right etc.

Comment: You would not create a larger canvas than the screen size, you would just re render the visible parts as needed. Eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925012/how-to-pan-the-canvas/33929456#33929456

Comment: Thanks! Really interesting solution that I have not come across. I have played with it for the past hour and its certainly an option so thank you a lot  but it feels like there should be a simpler solution?